# Descomprimir archivo concatenando variable con la fecha

Tags: linux, bash, línea-de-comandos

Deseo descomprimir un archivo en linux pero a la ruta quiero concatenarle una variable que cree a partir de una fecha, dejo el código que tengo hasta el momento, muchas gracias:

```
set fecha=$(date -d "today" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
set fecha1="$(date -d "${fecha}" +'%Y%m%d')"
cd /DWH/12_TRAFICO/0796_TRAF_IND_CALIDAD_PERSONAS/03_FUENTES/TEMPORAL/PRS && unzip '*$fecha1*.zip' && mv '2G_MEAS_CALL_KPI_BTS_HOUR-%fecha1%*.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta, desde la consola seria:

```
fecha=$(date -d "today" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');fecha1="$(date -d "${fecha}" +'%Y%m%d')";cd /DWH/12_TRAFICO/0796_TRAF_IND_CALIDAD_PERSONAS/03_FUENTES/TEMPORAL/PRS  && unzip $fecha1.zip && mv 2G_MEAS_CALL_KPI_BTS_HOUR-$fecha1.csv /falta/archivo/de/destino;
```

Comment: Pero tengo varios archivos en la ruta y quiero que me busque los que tengan esa fecha